# User input prints pre-selected list (python 2.6)

Tags: python-2.6

```
races=['Imperial', 'Nord', 'High Elf', 'Wood Elf', 'Dark Elf', 'Orc',    'Argonian']
race_desc=['Battle worthy! Able to find a few extra gold than normal',
       'Tough against warriors! 50% resistant to cold',
       'Esteem in Arcane Magic! 50+ extra magicka',
       'Masters of Archery! Increased skill in archery',
       'Destructive at will! Increased skill in destruction',
       'Buff and Mighty! Increased skill in two-handed weapons',
       'Feared reptiles! Underwater breathing ability']
def game():
    print "Welcome to The Elder Scrolls: Valenwood"
    print "Imperial, Nord, High Elf, Wood Elf, Dark Elf, Orc, Argonian"
    user_race=raw_input("Please select a race from above: ")
    for race in races:
        if user_race.title() == race:
            print "You've chosen an %s" % user_race.title()
    #HELP HERE

game()
```

I want the user to get an output from the race_desc list when they input a race. I have assigned the list in order, e.g input: Nord, output: "Tough against warriors..." or input: Argonian, output: "Feared reptiles..." Know what I mean? 
So i am hoping someone will be able to help me out with how I can make this work. Also I am using python 2.6.

Comment: so, what is your issue?  What error are you getting or not getting?

Comment: The issue is that I don't know how to create an output from the user's input. I am able to print what they have chosen but not the race_desc associated with user_race input because I do not know how to.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got it to work how I wanted it to:

```
for i in race_desc:
    if user_race.title() == i:
        print "You've chosen an %s. %s" % (user_race.title(), race_desc[i][0])
```

I had to change the race_desc into a dictionary:

```
race_desc={
    'Imperial' : ['Battle worthy! Able to find a few extra gold than normal'],
    'Nord' : ['Tough against warriors! 50% resistant to cold'],
    'High Elf' : ['Esteem in Arcane Magic! 50+ extra magicka'],
    'Wood Elf' : ['Master of the bow! Increased skill in archery'],
    'Dark Elf' : ['Destructive at will! Increased skill in destruction'],
    'Orc' : ['Buff and Mighty! Increased skill in two-handed weapons'],
    'Argonian' : ['Feared reptiles! Underwater breathing ability']
}
```